# Looping through a filter with arguments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, arguments

Im trying to filter the zeroth arguments of the function using the other arguments of the function. The loop and filter functions seem to be working but the problem seems to be that the loop doesn't loop all the way through. I'm not exactly sure what is going on in this case. Here is the code:

```
function destroyer(arr) {

    var args = Array.from(arguments);
    args.shift();

    function destroyer(value) {
        for (i = 0; i <= args.length; i++) {
            return value != args[i];
        }
    }
    return arguments[0].filter(destroyer);
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 30], 2, 3);
```

The output is `[1, 3, 1, 30]`.

Comment: What output do you expect? `[1,1,30]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
function destroyer(arr) {

    var args = Array.from(arguments);
    args.shift();
    function destroyer(value) {
        for (i = 0; i <= args.length; i++) {
            if(value == args[i]) 
                return false;  //If element is found, don't return
        } 
        return true; //Element not found in args
    }
    return arguments[0].filter(destroyer);
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 30], 2, 3);
```

**EDIT**: Why doesn't your approach work?

The problem is in this part:

The issue is in your return statement.

```
    for (i = 0; i <= args.length; i++) {
        return value != args[i];
    }
```

This will return the boolean value as soon as it sees compares the value in your array to the first value in the args array, ie it only compares to the first value.

Comment: Thanks that worked quite nicely. But what was the issue with the original code? I know the filter function requires a boolean to pass through but != produces a true/false response.

Comment: @amolinasf I have added the explanation. BTW, I see you are new to Stack Overflow, Welcome! Please accept and upvote the best answer to your question!